# Setting 'viewdir' does not work with :mkview

Tags: vimrc, gvim, vim-windows, window-management

I'm trying to use `:mkview` with `'viewdir'`.

I set `'viewdir'` as the help page said:

```
set viewdir='C:/Users/MyPC/vimfiles/view'
```

and made sure that `C:/Users/MyPc/vimfiles/view` exists, but I still get error messages when I use `:mkview`:

```
E739: Cannot create directory: 'C:/Users/MyPc/vimfiles/view'
E190: Cannot open "'C:/Users/MyPc/vimfiles/view'\~=+vimfiles=+view=+vi=" for writing.
```

How can I use `'viewdir'` with `:mkview`?

Comment: Don't use quotes around the file name.

Comment: [Please do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/). Instead, please [edit] and provide the actual content you want to be viewed.

Comment: Thanks @JürgenKrämer I removed the quotes and it worked

Comment: @PhamHung you should post and accept an informative self-answer to help others who might benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 2):

My problem here is caused by my single quote in `viewdir`

So I removed it and it's ok.